# src in script tag missing "http:"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, static-libraries

I've noticed that a lot of links to remote libraries are missing the `http:` from the src attribute: (this site uses it as well: that's where I got the example below)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is there an advantage in linking to remote files in this way? I know this question will probably get flagged because it doesn't call for a specific coding response, but I've searched for an answer without a whole lot of luck, probably because I don't know how to refer to it correctly.

Comment: If you didn't know if the site was going to be used over http: or https:, this would allow the same `src` to be used for either and avoid mixed secure/insecure warnings.

Comment: It's a *"[protocol-relative URL](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html)*". On an `http:` page, it inherits the `http:` protocol. On an `https:` page, it inherits `https:`. This prevents the browser's warning about parts of the page being secured (`https:`) and other parts not being secured (`http:`).

Comment: @Joe: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you for the lightning-fast response, sir. Much appreciated!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks for the link and the proper way to address this methodology.